# Что идет после собачки в запросе Oracle? ORA-02019: описание соединения для удаленной БД не найдено

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Есть проблема с запросом. Вылетает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема вот в этой вот строчке:

```
FROM time_batch_data@T4_BDB.VSW.RU tbd
```

Не разу не видел такого подключения, что идёт после собачки? Sid, host, service name? Подскажите пожалуйста кто в курсе. Не могу разобраться.

Сообщение об ошибке:

> ORA-02019: описание соединения для удаленной БД не найдено 02019.
>   02019, 00000 - "connection description for remote database not found"

Comment: Это [DB link - сохраненное соединение с другой DB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/ds_concepts.htm#ADMIN12084)

Comment: @MaxU а где его можно посмотреть? потому что тут оно указано как я понял не правильно. Мне нужно исправить это.

Comment: В представлениях (views): USER_DB_LINKS, ALL_DB_LINKS, DBA_DB_LINKS ...

Comment: @MaxU а поподробней можно? Где это смотреть?

Comment: @MaxU написал же что не разу не сталкивался с таким. Даже не знаю в какую сторону идти.

Comment: Пожалейте наши глаза и время — скопируйте текст ошибки непосредственно в вопрос. Само сообщение об ошибке лучше вынести  в заголовок, чтобы облегчить поиск в дальнейшем.

Comment: Идите в сторону документации - по ссылке из первого комментария... Если будут конкретные вопросы - задавайте их здесь... ;)

Comment: @MaxU в этой базе для которой делается запрос нет таких view.

Comment: @MaxU конкретный вопрос, где мне найти правильное название этого удалённого подключения. Если это не верно.

Comment: @defaultlocale `ORA-02019: описание соединения для удаленной БД не найдено
02019. 00000 -  "connection description for remote database not found"`

Comment: В указанных мною представлениях... Если у вас нет к ним доступа - обратитесь к вашему DBA...

Comment: @defaultlocale надеюсь это поможет

Comment: @Андрей поможет если добавите в вопрос. У Вас уже без малого 60 вопросов, как-то неудобно уже учить искать кнопку «править» под вопросом.

Comment: @defaultlocale да извиняюсь, просто сюда почему то добавил, уже есть в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Не разу не видел такого подключения, что идёт после собачки?

Как уже написали в комментариях после собачки идет название [Database Link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/ds_concepts.htm#ADMIN12083) — ссылки на другую БД Oracle (`T4_BDB.VSW.RU`).

Если раскроете соединение в SQL Developer, то сможете найти раздел «Database Links».

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раскройте его и найдите в списке `T4_BDB.VSW.RU`. Далее можете попробовать просмотреть свойства соединения (`SERVICE NAME`, наименование, используемая учетная запись) и отредактировать их (`Edit`). Также должна быть доступна опция `Test Database Link` для проверки связи.

Перед тем как что-то менять настоятельно рекоммендую ознакомиться с документацией и понять с чем Вы имеете дело, для каких целей создан и используется DBLink.

> ORA-02019: описание соединения для удаленной БД не найдено 02019.

Ошибка говорит о недоступности ссылки на удаленную БД. Причин может быть множество, например:

- Ссылка с таким имененем не была создана вообще. В этом случае Вам нужно будет разобраться почему Вы хотите запрашивать данные из этой БД и где она находится.
- Ссылка создана, но удаленная БД недоступна. В этом случае нужно проверить существует ли удаленная БД вообще и доступна ли она с ***сервера*** текущей БД.